# Kak распределить итерации цикла на несколько процессов?

Tags: python, многопоточность, оптимизация

Есть цикл, делающий `N` итераций.

Как максимально просто (можно использовать сторонние библиотеки) распределить итерации этого цикла на `P` процессов, чтобы ускориться примерно в `P` раз?

Следующая итерация не зависит от результатов предыдущей.

Comment: советую более широко описать задачу, чтобы было, как минимум, понятно на что тратится большая часть времени - IO, CPU или что-то другое. Для того, чтобы дать действительно дельный совет, нужно хорошо понимать суть проблемы. С текущей формулировкой вопроса можно дать только поверхностный совет...

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Из известных мне модулей, максимально просто это реализовано в [joblib.Parallel](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html):

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> from joblib import Parallel, delayed
>>> Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

**NOTE:** при распараллеливании работы на `N` частей, практически никогда не удаётся достичь ускорения в `N` раз. Всегда существуют накладные расходы. В некоторых редких случаях после распараллеливания код работает даже медленнее чем исходный последовательный вариант.