# Распределение закачки на несколько процессов

Tags: python, многопоточность, оптимизация, crawling

Есть `requests.Session`, который в цикле с помощью `.get()` скачивает данные с последовательных страниц сайта `site.com/data/1`, ..., `site.com/data/N` и сохраняет их в множестве `data = set()`, т.е. порядок сохранения не важен. Данные следующей страницы не зависят от предыдущей. Можно ли как-то ускорить это дело, распараллелив этот цикл? Например, 1 процесс качает и сохраняет первые `N / {кол-во процессов}` страниц, второй - вторые и т.д.. Можно даже не синхронизировать `data`, а скачивать в свои `data_1`, ..., `data_N`, а уже после закачки их объединить `data_1 | ... | data_N`.

Comment: Уточнение вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1252918/433144

Comment: для этого (задач, где параллельный I/O) и придумали asyncio. aiohttp вместо requests.